# What helm repository should I add?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am following these instructions (https://docs.rocket.chat/installation/paas-deployments/eks) which use `helm`.
However helm seems to have changed since these instructions were written and a 'repository' is now required.

My question is :

#### What repo should I add for helm v3 that is the equivalent to helm v2 default ?

---

**Here is what I have done**

I tried the command `helm init --service-account tiller`
but received the error, **Error: unknown command "init" for "helm**.
I read [here](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-v3-beta/#:%7E:text=The%20helm%20init%20command%20has%20been%20removed.&text=Helm%20now%20follows%20the%20XDG,searched%20by%20the%20Helm%20Hub.) that init is no longer required for helm.

So I tried the next command to install traefik, `helm install stable/traefik --name traefik --namespace kube-system --set rbac.enabled=true`.
and that says **Error: unknown flag: --name** which is also a change for v3,
So I adjust the command to be `helm install traefik stable/traefik  --namespace kube-system --set rbac.enabled=true`.
And now I get **Error: failed to download "stable/traefik" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)**.
`helm repo update` returns **Error: no repositories found. You must add one before updating**

I tried `helm repo add stable` but got **Usage:  helm repo add [NAME] [URL] [flags]**

In the [update documentation](https://helm.sh/blog/helm-v3-beta/) I am not finding anything about what that **NAME** or **URL** should be.

So, another way to ask my question is :

#### What values should [NAME] and [URL] be for the `helm repo add` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is :

**`helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com`**

- https://github.com/helm/charts